# Unable to load authentication plugin with MySQL Authentication Plugin

Tags: java, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I'm encountering an error in my MySQL application, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. I'm using MySQL Connector/J to connect to a MySQL database, and I keep encountering the following error message:

> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'auth_gssapi_client'

Here are some additional details about my setup:

The MySQL server version is 8.
I am using java and apache tomcat
The error occurs when I attempt to connect to the database using the domain connection URL: [Ex:- http://xyz:8080/abc].
Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

In local server is working fine but On server through error

> 19-Feb-2024 14:23:09.678 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dms] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection] with root cause
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'auth_gssapi_client'.

Comment: *...using the domain connection URL:...* What is that and why would you use it?

Comment: Domin url like "http://example.com:8080/".. I want to use my java application in publicly. ln locally, its working but publicly throw error.  
database.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/dms?useSSL=false
#database.url = jdbc:mysql://IP:3307/dmsdb?user=admin&password=pass123&useSSL=false
database.user=root
database.password=admin@123
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.connection.autocommit=true

Comment: So you want to connect to a remote db and you *don't* have a webapp?

Comment: I've developed an application with a database configuration (please refer to my previous comment). When I access the index page, the login page loads successfully. However, upon attempting to log in from a public domain, the application throws the error mentioned above.

Comment: I now see from the stack trace that you *do* have a webapp, sorry. Are you *intending* to use auth_gssapi_client deliberately?

Comment: Sorry Sir, What is the meaning of this and How can I resolve this, help me...

Comment: You're using auth_gssapi_client. Why?

Comment: I am not using, I found this error when hit the database?